# SWTBot - why can't run the same class using JUnit4TestAdapter?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4, swtbot

I'm using SWTBot to run automation on my enviroment.
I've created 2 Suites and 2 test cases in each - the problem is that I used the same Test case for both suites.

```
TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("Test Suite 1");
suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Test1.class));
suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Test2.class));

TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("Test Suite 2");
suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Test1.class));
suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Test2.class));
```

when I run the SWTBot, it runs only one suite twice.. see my code here:

### AllTestSuites.java - Main class which build all suites

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@SuiteClasses({
    SuiteOneAllTests.class, 
    SuiteTwoAllTests.class })
....//Code..
```

### SuiteOneAllTests.java

```
public class SuiteOneAllTests extends TestSuite {

    /**
     * Function for running all test cases
     * @return suite (All test cases)
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static Test suite() throws Exception {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("Test Suite 1");

        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Test1.class));
        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Test2.class));

        return suite;
    }
}
```

### SuiteTwoAllTests.java

```
public class SuiteTwoAllTestsextends TestSuite {

    /**
     * Function for running all test cases
     * @return suite (All test cases)
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static Test suite() throws Exception {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("Test Suite 1");

        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Test1.class));
        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Test2.class));

        return suite;
    }
}
```

And here is the results:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPgHY.jpg

Comment: what's the stacktrace displayed in junit view ?

Comment: I don't have any stacktrace... it just get back on the same class again

Comment: Try executing only the Test Suite 2